# How to log to console when using IEFrame.dll

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6, ieframe.dll

I'm working on a legacy application that is written in VB6 and uses the IEFrame.dll.  There is some JavaScript that is not running consistently and I'd like to write some logs somewhere to help figure out what is going on.  Is this even possible with IEFrame.dll?

Comment: do you mean your vb6 windows form application is using the MS WBC (web browser control)? It will default to using IE7 emulation if that is the case. add alert(document.documentMode) to a button in your html markup to determine which IE emulation mode is being used... There are registry settings for FEATURE_CONTROL_BROWSER_EMULATION which over-ride the default IE7 emulation of a WBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make some people cringe, but consider the following:

sample.htm

```
<html xmlns:custom>
    <body>
        <custom:generic id="Logging" style="inline:true;display:none"/>

        <button onclick="Logging.innerText='Hello';Logging.click()">Click me 1</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button onclick="Logging.innerText='Goodbye';Logging.click()">Click me 2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Form1.frm

```
Option Explicit

'Reference to: Microsoft HTML Object Library

Private WithEvents Logging As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement

Private Sub Form_Load()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate2 App.Path & "\sample.htm"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
    If WindowState <> vbMinimized Then
        WebBrowser1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
    End If
End Sub

Private Function Logging_onclick() As Boolean
    Debug.Print Logging.innerText
End Function

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Set Logging = pDisp.Document.All("Logging")
End Sub
```

Comment: In case it in't clear `Debug.Print` above can be replaced by any valid code to log the text wherever you want it (a file, a console window, another Form, etc.).